# Component AV, higher resolution source into lower reciever?

Tags: analog, formats

If I have for example 720 or 1080 component (analog YPBPR) output from one device going into another device that only does 576 will it work ? what will be the result ?

Comment: I might add that the dvbt modulator (reciever) doesnt specifically set any input limits, more that it outputs at 576...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work... that will be the result :-) The answer is in your question: if the device ***only*** does 576, then it won't handle anything else.

Comment: Heads up - this post was flagged - can you add some background..?

Comment: @Mulvya are you talking to me or the answerer ?

Comment: The answerer. But you could update the question with the model numbers of the two devices.